# SYN-flood to the localhost Apache server

Tags: denial-of-service, tcp, flooding

I've set up the apache server on localhost (127.0.0.1). I've downloaded PackETH to perform a DoS attack. So PackETH wants  MAC-HEADER of the destination and source. And I don't know, where to find them.
[image: Where are mac's ?]

Comment: What is the purpose of this experiment?

Comment: @Limit,to perform Dos attack to my own server , using syn-flood

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ipconfig /all` command in the Windows command prompt and then copy your Physical Address, also known as MAC address. I am not sure if PackETH will work on the same PC though.

More detail [here](https://kb.netgear.com/1005/How-to-find-a-MAC-address).

Comment: ,How does it work? Should I find the mac adress of lchalhost ? it is impossile

Comment: @Elvin i actually don't think it is possible to have mac of localhost. You probably want to get your local network MAC. Though I don't know whether it will send the packets over the network or realize it is its own mac or whether it will even arrive. It would be best to have two computers/virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux, open terminal and run `ifconfig` command. You'll find the MAC address under "HWaddr" (Hardware Address)
You can find additional details [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uifconfi.htm).

TMHO. I think you better use 2 virtual machines with NAT Network and not attack your local machine with external tools you did not wrote yourself.